# Public functions vs Functions in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, methods

In PHP, What is the difference between declaring methods inside class like

`public function`  VS `function`

For example:

```
public function contact()
{
    $data['header'] = "Contact";
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_contact', $data);
}
```

VS

```
function contact()
{
    $data['header'] = "Contact";
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_contact', $data);
}
```

Is it better practice to use **public function** or **function** and why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Methods declared with any explicit visibility keyword is best practice. It looks and feels better and it doesn't confuse people.

- Most PHP5 coding conventions (e.g. Zend, Symfony...) require the public keyword, so it's familiar.
- It means that variable and method declarations use the same syntax.
- It's more explicit and forces developers to consider their method 
  visibility.

Answer (score 15):

According to [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

> Class methods may be defined as public, private, or protected. **Methods declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as public**.

for best practice, i suggest using visibility keywords (esp when using higher versions of PHP). it prevents confusion (like the one you are in now) and promotes standard practice in coding.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between these two.
Both are the same.
In codeigniter both have same meaning
and can be called by using standard URI tags unless you give a '_' in front of your function name
 `_fname()` will not be called

Answer (score 3):

They are the same thing .... if you do not specify the visibility methods / functions are declared as `public`

> Methods declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as public

from the [docs here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want best practice you will always use public. But for the codeigniter Framework it doesn't mather if you declare it public or not. Note that if you want a controller to be private you dont use private but you will use the underscore (_) in front of your controller name so it wont be visible.

Answer (score 0):

- Both declarations are same and both functions will be available by URI request in codeigniter
- To prevent a method from being called by user use private or protected access specifiers.