# Codeigniter subdomain wildcard get account every method

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter with dynamic subdomains,  but in each method of my controllers I need to get the account of the dynamic subdomain. I'm looking for a way to get the domain and add to the $data without to it every method like:

```
    <?php

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $subdomain_arr = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 2);

        $subdomain_name = $subdomain_arr[0];

        $this->db->from('accounts')->where('subdomain', $subdomain_name);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $account = $query->row();

        $data['account_id'] = $account->id;

        $data['account_name'] = $account->name;

        $this->load->view('index', $data);
    }

    function clients()
    {
        $subdomain_arr = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 2);

        $subdomain_name = $subdomain_arr[0];

        $this->db->from('accounts')->where('subdomain', $subdomain_name);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $account = $query->row();

        $data['account_id'] = $account->id;

        $data['account_name'] = $account->name;

        $this->load->view('clients', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it once within a [Class Constructor](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#constructors) and then you can access the same variables from all of the other methods.

[As per docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#constructors):

> *"Constructors are useful **if you need to set some default values**, or run a default process when your class is instantiated. Constructors can't return a value, but they can do some default work."*

```
<?php

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    public $data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $subdomain_arr = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 2);
        $subdomain_name = $subdomain_arr[0];
        $this->db->from('accounts')->where('subdomain', $subdomain_name);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $account = $query->row();
        $this->data['account_id'] = $account->id;
        $this->data['account_name'] = $account->name;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->data;  // contains your values from the constructor above

        $data['title'] = "My Index";  // also use your $data array as normal

        $this->load->view('index', $data);
    }

    public function clients()
    {
        $data = $this->data;  // contains your values from the constructor above

        $this->load->view('clients', $data);
    }

}
```

*NOTE:  Even though CodeIgniter functions default to "public", it's best practice to declare them as such.  See:  [Public functions vs Functions in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9849984/594235)*

Comment: There are some way to create my custom controller and extend all from my controller, to hide the constructor method where I get the account data?

Comment: @cristianormoraes, I don't understand the grammar or wording of your comment.